# How to get the file mime type of another branch using git command java

Tags: java, git

I am working on getting git into a IDE, and I require to know the type of the file without checkout the exact branch.

That is suppose I am in `branch_A` and there is a file called `sample.xxx` in `branch_B`, how can I get the file mime type like `text/x-java`,  `application/x-yaml`, `image/png`, etc without actually switching to the branch, I am able to read the file without switching over, so I think it is possible to read the type too.

Comment: This smells fishy.  Why do you think you want this?

Comment: Just a new type project work.  I trying to get the accurate data from all branches, without actually switching to that branch.  So when I try to read a file,  I can't read a zip or image file right,  so I could try to get the mime type first so that I can decide if I can read that file or not.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't store the mime type of any of the files in the repository. On most systems this can only be inferred from the filename extension, or by examining the content of the file.